# Is it safe to use 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 implementation in case of cyclic dependencies?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Does using 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 terminate gracefully if there are cyclic dependencies in a dl (a -> b -> a situation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` OID handles circular dependencies just fine. It won't choke on them.

For example, I recommended using this when determining if [a user is a member of a group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/09/13/one-user-is-member-of-a-group.html#the-slightly-harder-but-still-easy-way).

Consider if you have this setup:

- `Group A`

  - `Group B`
- `Group B`

  - `User 1`
  - `Group A`

And you want to know if `User 1` is a member of `Group A`. You would set the search base to `Group A`, and use this query:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=User 1,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com)
```

The query would succeed (it won't choke on the circular groups) and you would get 1 result (`Group A`) indicating that yes, `User 1` is a member of `Group A`. (If you got no results, it would mean that the user is not a member of the group)

You should never use a `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` condition without either limiting the search base or using other conditions (like matching a specific account), otherwise you will end up with a *very* inefficient query that will take forever to run because it has to look at the entire membership chain for every object that exists.